# Trouble adding to a circular linked list

Tags: c++, nodes, circular-list

I am trying to write a doubly circular linked list. According to my understand the code should in fact create a circular linked list.

1. I start with the special case where the first node would have its previous and next node point to itself.
2. Afterwards a temp node is made which has its next node point to the current head, then have the current head's `pPrev` pointer point back to this temp node. This should establish the link between temp and the rest of the list. Then I make temp's `pPrev` go to the tail and then the tail's `pNext` go to temp which I think should handle the circularity. And then to close I change temp to become the new head.

When I print from the head pointer the only thing that prints is the first node over and over again. I am not seeing where I am going wrong with this implementation. If anyone could give me and tips as to where I am going wrong that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

```
void addNodeToStart(Node*& pHead, Node*& pTail, int input) {
    Node* pTemp = new Node;
    pTemp->data = input;

    if (pHead == NULL) {
        pTemp->data = input;
        pTemp->pNext = pTemp;
        pTemp->pPrev = pTemp;

        pHead = pTemp;
        pTail = pTemp;
    } else {
        pTemp->pNext = pHead;
        pHead->pPrev = pTemp;
        pTemp->pPrev = pTail;
        pTail->pNext = pTemp;
    }

    pHead = pTemp;
}
```

Comment: Code seems to be fine. How are you calling the function??? Maybe you are passing NULL value to pHead everytime!!

Comment: it is OK, http://ideone.com/rL4goi, probably you print wrong

Comment: I have Node *pHead = NULL; Node *pTail = NULL; at the top of my main. And then a have a do-while loop for the multiple input numbers a user could input in which I call the function with addNodeToStart( pHead, pTail, input); Once the null is passed the first time I think the if( pHead == NULL) {} part of my code changes the NULL part

Comment: How do you print? It work for me.

Comment: It seems to work for me, but you don't need that second `pTemp->data = input`. And does it really make sense for a circular linked list to have a tail?

Comment: `void printAtStart( Node* pHead)
{
   while( pHead != NULL) {
      cout << pHead->data << endl;
      pHead = pHead->pNext;       
   }  
   cout << endl;   
}`    Why would this only print the first input in an infinite loop rather than all the inputs put in?

Comment: This would cycle forever, you need to test with `pHead` (remember circular), the only case `pHead == NULL` is when empty. Try this: `void printAtStart(Node* pHead) { Node* tmp = pHead; while (pHead != NULL) { cout << pHead->data << endl; pHead = pHead->pNext; if (pHead == tmp) break; } cout << endl; }`

Comment: One technique to use (this is described in CLRS: Introduction to Algorithms, among other places) is to create a special "sentinel" node that acts as the head and tail node.  Give this node a special value, possibly numeric_limits<int>::max(), and use this to determine when you've reached the head/tail of the list.

Comment: You should not reset your pHead, because this is your starting point. You add elements to pHead->next, then make all necessary references, and then the last element you add should be the pTail. Your pTail->next should make a reference to pHead->pPrev, this will make it circular. Make sure you are making a reference to pHead pointer`s memory address, otherwise you might be making a reference to another node that you a not supposed to. You can always check by adding elements to pHead then printf to confirm the number of elements you have added so far. Before joining the pHead with the pTail.

Comment: Out of desperation I copy/pasted my code just as it was from Dev C++ to Visual Studio and it worked fine... Anyways thank you all for your help, I did get quite a lot of useful insight form you all..